# Realloc function seems to not work! This program is from a textbook

Tags: c, crash, realloc

My code (or the example from the book) seems to not work. I know it's the realloc function causing this, since I will allocate some memory to a set amount at the beginning. If I surpass the original amount I allocated, I will realloc() to increase the allocation.

The allocated memory is for a bunch of pointers, the more pointers I need, the more memory I need. These pointers will ultimately point to a string from an input. Regardless, the crashing occurs whenever I try to access the data at the string during a specific situation.

I set my COUNT (the amount I allocate originally) to let's say 5. It will crash after the sixth input. But, if I only have 5, no crashing. Thus, I believe this has something to do with realloc().

```
#define COUNT 5 // Initial number of strings
//code in between here

// ...
char** psTemp = NULL; // Temporary pointer to pointer to char
char* pTemp = NULL; // Temporary pointer to char
size_t str_count = 0; // Current string count
size_t capacity = COUNT; // Current maximum number of strings
// ...

if (str_count == capacity)
    {
        capacity += capacity / 4; // Increase capacity by 25%
        if (!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity))) return 1;
        pS = psTemp;
    }
```

Above you can see my COUNT and realloc() function. I will update the allocation whenever I reach limit, when my current number of input (str_count) reaches the current allocation (capacity).

I've tried this in Visual Studio and Pelles C and both give me similar issues.

In Wisual Studio '13, it will crash after my 6th input, since my allocation is originally set to five.

In Pelles C, it will crash after my 8th input, why? I have no clue.

I ran it through the debugger, the `realloc()` works, and the updated allocation works, yet it crashes.

I'm trying to self teach my self C but this book has too many of these weird errors!

Here is my code, I have `realloc()` occur only once in my code: http://ideone.com/bY6CXk.

Comment: The program you linked to doesn't even compile.

Comment: It won't compile on ideone because I'm using optional string functions. It will compile in windows studio or pelles c

Comment: That wasn't the only problem. The code also contains statements invalid in C89 (which ideone supports).

Answer (score 1):

You're not scaling the size of the allocation by the type of the data. This means you're just allocating `capacity` bytes, when you probably need `capacity * sizeof *psTemp`. This assumes the type of `psTemp` is proper, i.e. not `void *`. If you had shown more code it would be easier to help.

Comment: I shared with you my entire code, please click on the ideone link!
Thanks though, it worked! Why DIDNT THE GUY WHO WROTE THE BOOK DO THAT?

Comment: @LivePresently Many authors don't know C very well, yet write books about it. Stick with K&R.

Comment: @LivePresently We can't possibly answer that since we don't know what book you're talking about. It could well be that the book is fine and that you didn't adapt it correctly. Perhaps the book allocates char arrays, where the element size is 1 so no multiply is required.

Comment: I copied the code. I did not alter it in any way. This was one purely from the book it's this one :http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/1430248815?pc_redir=1408425121&robot_redir=1

Comment: Unfortunately, software textbooks are notorious for non-working code.